# Blank page after updating to vuejs 2.0

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

i'm sure it's a simple thing for you but i lost already hours for that. i'm trying to upgrade my application to 2.0.

I used vuejs on top of the application for some functionality, not as vuejs application. That worked so far with vuejs 1.

previously initiate on body element. but now i get an empty page. i also wrapped it in a  div and called it:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="app-wrapper">
            <h1>My stuff</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

i understand that it does overwrite my div content but how can then apply it to a already rendered page? Or how can i load the rendered page into that div again?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you add `id="app"` to your `<div>`?

Comment: yes of course. i will update the main post with that

Comment: Can you give more specific detail? Maybe you can upload your file to `pastebin`, `gist` or `jsfiddle` so everyone can see. I don't see why your app doesn't work with Vue 2.x

Comment: Is that your complete Vue definition? Possibly you specified a template somewhere?

Comment: do you get an error in the console?

Comment: Show us your route definition, it should contain some information that could help us to identify the error.

Answer (score 4):

Thank's guys for you help.

At the the end, the issue was because I use **Webpack** and the I need to add to the webpack configuration file.

```
//webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  entry: {...},
  output: {...},
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js'
    },
  },
  ...
};
```

---

**Updated 02/06/2020**

From [dist/README.md](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/dist/README.md) VueJS

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js' // 'vue/dist/vue.common.js' for webpack 1
    }
  }
}
```